# how to load html from server and use jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-load

I have a div on .aspx page:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

and I am loading some html from server using jQuery .load() method as below:

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').load('web/testpage');
});
```

where web/testpage is mvc partial view:

```
<div id='partialView'>
   blah blah
</div>
```

This loads correctly and I see the expected mark-up in the firebug

```
<div id="container">
   <div id='partialView'>
      blah blah
   </div>
</div>
```

but the problem is I am not able to select the inner div from jQuery

```
$(function() {
   console.log($('#partialView')); // this is empty
});
```

any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until the div is loaded, you can use the callback from `.load` for this:

```
$('#container').load('web/testpage', function() {
    console.log($('#partialView'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't select `#partialView` on DOMReady, because it has not been loaded in to the page until the `load()` function completes.

If you need to perform logic on this element, you would need to use the callback parameter of `load()`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').load('web/testpage', function() {
        console.log($('#partialView')); // "[Object object]"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the load method [Callback Function](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').load('web/testpage', function (response) {
        console.log($('#partialView'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is right but I think your "console.log(....)" function is invoking before loading the partial view. so you are getting nothing.